# Finding average of vector

Tags: c++

I've only recently start programming and I've got this task to create a vector, ask the user for input values which are then appended to the vector and then the average is taken of the values entered.

Right now, what I have is this:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<numeric>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<float> v;
    float input;

    cout << " Enter values" <<endl;
    while (cin >> input)
        v.push_back(input);

    float average = accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0/v.size());
    cout << "The average is " << average <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think I'm calculating the average wrong because when I test it, it just adds the numbers instead of finding the average. What is it that I need to change?

Answer (score 3):

So you've just got the brackets wrong

```
float average = accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0) / v.size();
```

not

```
float average = accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0/v.size());
```

Your version did `0.0/v.size()` which obviously is zero. Instead you want to divide the result of `accumulate` by the size.

Comment: thank you very much, that fixed that. i have another issue where i'm trying to get the program to stop and calculate the average once the user enters a negative number. for example, if i type 1 2 3 4 -5, it should discard the -5 and show the average of the first four numbers. how can i do this?

Comment: Well you need to change your while loop so that it stops looping if the input number is less than zero. Have a go yourself first, you don't learn much when you are just told the answer.

Comment: Or to put it another way (maybe easier) your while loop should only continue looping when the input number is greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: i put in if (input < 0) break; and it seems to work, is that the best way to do it?

Comment: oh wait, i have a problem. when i do this is appends it to the vector instead of discarding it like i want

Comment: Personally I would have done this `while (cin >> input && input >= 0) ...` but your way works as well.

Comment: That's probably because you put the `if ... break` after the `push_back`, if you put it before it should work.